# Why .OSM file contains untagged nodes?

Tags: openstreetmap

The .osm file I have:

```
// Weird part of the file
<node id="104511" lat="52.1696253" lon="0.131889" 
      version="3" timestamp="2013-03-05T18:51:38Z" 
      changeset="15262147" uid="103253" user="gormur"
/>
```

contains nodes that apart from latitude and longitude have
no other meaningful info (in my opinion). I have no idea whether such node is a building, a bus stop, or an intersection of two streets.

1) Why do people add such nodes into the file?

2) What's a simple way to remove such nodes from .OSM and leave file only with tagged nodes, such as:

```
<node id="104520" lat="52.1951248" lon="0.1312155" ...>
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
</node>
```

3) Could an untagged node indicate the intersection of 2 streets? Will I realize which streets the node intersects by looking to which ways it belongs? How can I know such node is the intersection of 2 streets rather than a building on the corner of 2 streets?

Answer (score 2):

Not all nodes have/need tags.

[Nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) that are part of a [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) (a street, a building, a forest etc.) just exist to define the geometry of that way. In that case all the necessary tags ([highway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway), [building](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/key:building), [landuse](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:landuse) and so on) are on the corresponding *way* and not on the *node*. A way keeps a reference to all nodes it consists of. So in order to know if a node is part of a building you have  to take a look at the way it belongs to (if it belongs to a way). Also note that a node can belong to multiple ways, or to no way at all.

It depends on the specific feature if the tags are primarily used on nodes, ways or relations. Buildings for example are mostly mapped as ways, sometimes as relations and rarely as nodes. Contrary, bus stops are mostly just nodes.

For more information take a look at the [OSM XML file format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML), [OSM elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [OSM tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags).

Comment: Few questions to make sure I understand what you said: (i) could a long building be labeled as a way having several nodes? (ii) when a street is labeled as a way having a list of nodes, could some of these nodes stand just for a point on that street, but not for any object?

Comment: I suggest to just take a look at the data in an OSM editor and I'm pretty sure everything will become much clearer to you.

Yes, a long building (and also a short one) will consist of a way having multiple (mostly untagged) nodes. However some nodes can have tags to represent entrances or POIs.

Yes, streets usually just consists if multiple untagged nodes, too. However some nodes can still have a tag, for example for crossings, bus stops etc.

Remember that nodes are required to define the *geometry* of objects.